# What am I overlooking as I attempt to account for nil?

Tags: swift, xcode7.2

I've reread the Swift documentation a number of times, but I'm afraid I'm overlooking something simple here.

The function below processes just fine and properly calls the updateCalorieBalance method if there is value in the field caloriesConsumed.text. But, of course, crashes if caloriesConsumed.text is nil.

The error message I get is: fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value.

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

```
@IBAction func buttonThree(sender: AnyObject) {

    var calConsumed: String?

    if let calConsumed = caloriesConsumed.text {
        calorieCount.updateCalorieBalance(Double(calConsumed)!)
        balanceLabel.text = "New Balance: \(Int((calorieCount.getCalorieBalance())))"
    } else {
        balanceLabel.text = "Please enter calories to add."
    }

    caloriesConsumed.resignFirstResponder()
}
```

Comment: Perhaps check whether `Double(calConsumed)` results in a non-nil rather than forcing it?

Comment: Did you try deleting `var calConsumed: String?` at the top?

Comment: You should try writing your method without the crash operator `!`

Answer (score 1):

calConsumed should not be an optional string. Actually, "if let" creates its own variable so you now have two variables with the same name...

Double (calConsumed) returns nil if calConsumed is an *empty string* or a string not containing a number. The ! that you use will make it crash.

```
if let calText = caloriesConsumed.text, 
       calNumber = Double (calText) {
    ...
}
```

(Not tested or even compiled).

Comment: adding the calNumber = Double (calText) to the method cleared things up.    Thanks.